# How to use mongodb lookup aggregation with sort?

Tags: mongodb

From my `connection_dags_archived`
collection, the following lookup works, giving me the joined items in an array:
[image]

But when I wish to move it into a pipeline to add sorting, it fails:

[image]

And when even the sorting is removed, the array is empty:

[image]

How do I add sorting on the join?

Comment: you missed the $ reference in `let: { 'job_id': '$job_id' }`

Comment: The sort still times out :(

Comment: By default aggregation in MongoDB occurs in memory and pipeline stages have limit of 100 Mb RAM. try to use `allowDiskUse" : true` option in aggregation query.

Comment: @turivishal thanks, I've added that but it still times out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "steps_archived" collection does not have index on "timestamp" field, so the query times out because it takes too much time to execute.
Add index to that field and increase "execution timeout" option and try again.

Comment: Thanks, but there is already an index on that field. I also tried another index field and that also times out. Any idea why that would happen?